# laravel 8: BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\UsersGestionController::show does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have this error when i want to call my method update, dispite i have no show mrthid in my UsersGestionController

Thank you for help

UserGestionController.php :

```
 public function utilisateurlist()
    {
        $usersList = User::orderBy('id_role', 'desc')->take(50)->get();
        return view('events.ListeUtilisateur', ['usersList' => $usersList]);
    }
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $id=$request->id;
        $name=$request->name;
        $email=$request->email;
        $id_role=$request->id_role;

        $update = [
            'id'=> $id,
            'name'=> $name,
            'email'=> $email,
            'id_role'=> $id_role,
        ];
        User:where('id',$request->id)->update($update);
        return redirect()->route('userlist');
    }
```

web.php :

```
Route::get('/userslist', function () {
    return view('users.ListeUtilisateur');
});
Route::resource('events', EventsController::class);
Route::resource('users', UsersGestionController::class);
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get(
        '/userslist',
        [App\Http\Controllers\UsersGestionController::class, 'utilisateurlist'])->name('userslist');

Route::get('page1', function () { return view("page1"); })->middleware('auth');

Route::post('update',[App\Http\Controllers\UsersGestionController::class,'update'])->name('update');
```

list.blade.php :

```
      <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{route('users.update',$users->id)}}">Update</a>
```

Comment: you have a hyperlink to the URL pattern of  `users/{id}` which would be the SHOW route, not the UPDATE route since hyperlinks will cause a GET request ... you would need to submit a form with a spoofed method of `PUT` or `PATCH` to hit your UPDATE route .... are you perhaps trying to send someone to the EDIT page with that link where you would have a form for them to submit?

Answer (score -1):

you need to import correctly your controller on web.php routes and to change your route like :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersGestionController;

Route::post('update',[UsersGestionController::class,'update'])->name('update');
```